# Issue in updating database with jpa in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa, eclipselink

In our application, we want to update some records based on their current status. In database table, we have 2 fields named status and notified, when status is active, and notified is 0, we need to update notified to 1. Since the data will get inserted and updated continuously, I wrote a thread to scan the table periodically. 
Here is the pseudo code for the thread:

```
public class DataPublisher implements Runnable {
private JPADAO dao;

public DataPublisher(JPADAO dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    List<Entity> list = dao.getUpdateInformation();
    for(Entity entity : list) {
        dao.updateNotifiedStatus(entity.getId());
    }
}
}
```

I run the thread with a scheduled thread pool.
  I used jpa to update the database. The code to update the status is like this:

```
public class JPADAO {
private EntityManager em;

public JPADAO(EntityManager em) {
    if(em == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("Invalid em argument.");
    this.em = em;
}

public void updateNotifiedStatus(String id) {
    EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();
    Entity request = em.find(Entity.class, id);
    request.setNotified(1);
    transaction.commit();
```

}

When I start the application, the issue is, the first time, all the data will get updated correctly. When I manually changed the field notified to 0 with database client, the thread can find that they match the condition to be updated. But they will never get updated to 1 anymore.
Why the data will not get updated in a thread?

---

Just an update:
I have solved this issue. The main reason for it is that in my side, my process will access the database with jpa. But other process is also accessing the same one in a different way. Since jpa will read the data from cache by default. Everytime in my query, it will only get the data from cache without knowing that the database has changed. So to get the newest updated data from database, we need to disable cache in eclipselink. Here is the configurations I added:

```
<property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
<property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="0"/>
<property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="None"/>
```

Comment: Try calling `em.flush()` before `transaction.commit()`, it sometimes helps with updates.

Answer (score 0):

First, this looks like something that should be handled in the entity, so that if status and notification values are changed to active and 0 respectively, the business logic itself changes the notification value to 1.

Second, I'm not sure how the DataPublisher instance is used in the pool, but there is only a single instance that gets reused, it means you are using the same EntityManager over and over.  Because EntityManagers cache managed instances, each find call returns the entity it has cached with that id - the first call loads the data from the db while subsequent iterations will only get the cached data.  The cached entity will already have its notification value set to 1 , so there is nothing for JPA to change.

There are a few ways around this.  Close the em in the dao when done and obtain new ones when needed; clear the em after the transaction commits so it can be reused and the entities current state released, or use em.refresh on the entity to force the changes be pulled into the context from the database.